# SQLAlchemy relationship or association_proxy through several models(tables)

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, relationship

I have several tables, connected as a chain with One-to-many relationships (names are changed to emphasise, there is a chain):

Country <- City <- Street <- House

I need to have an attribute in House model to access it's only one Country.

Street is connected to House using relationship, as well as City is connected to Street and Country to City. There is an absolutely clear chain.
I already had a problem, connecting House to City, but solved it using Association_proxy:

```
class House(db.Model):
    ...
    street= db.relationship('Street', foreign_keys='House.street_id', backref='streets')
    city = association_proxy('street', 'city')

class Street(db.Model):
        ...
        city = db.relationship('City', foreign_keys='Street.city_id', backref='streets')

class City(db.Model):
        ...
        country = db.relationship('Country', foreign_keys='City.country_id', backref='cities')
```

But none of this helped me to connect the Country to House.
I need to filter by Country, so @property does not help.
Yes, it seems that filtering by Association_proxy or relationship is not implemented in SQLAlchemy (I had an Exception), but I already solved it too, created special method to filter.
Association_proxy seems to use only two model names: first as an immediate target and second as the final target. Or is there a way to use more?

I also did find a part ["Composite “Secondary” Joins"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/join_conditions.html#composite-secondary-joins) of Relationships docs, but it seems to be used in more difficult cases (I don't get, why there should be a_id in C-table, I don't have House_id in City and don't find it to be necessary). Or did I miss something?

So now **I need a way to get Country from House** using one of these methods. Is there a way to use several models as proxy or straightforward relationship through them?
I did not find a good explanation in the docs. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for a better final solution, but got some advises, which are not perfect, but may solve a problem in some cases...

1. Create an additional association_table with Many-to-Many relationships.
   For example, an association_table with such columns:

   id - country_id - city_id - street_id - house_id (house_id is unique).

In this case we well be able to get a City or Country for any House.

Answer (score 0):

2. If we deal with objects, not Model, @property can get us a Country (but filtering by property does not exists on DB level, so it can be done only on app level by our hands):

   @property

   def country(self):

   ```
    return db.session.query(House).filter(House.id==self.id).join(Street).filter(Street.id==House.street_id).join(City).filter(City.id==Street.street_id).join(Country).filter(Country.id==City.country_id).first().country
   ```